# How to search account name if the account number inputed is in the file in java?

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I have already a record in my insert.txt which contains the accno,accname and deposit then I 
put a delimeter(;)

my insert.txt contains the ff:

12345;kean;10000

54321;allen;20000

32154;imam;10000

How will I display the accname if i have entered the accno?
for example i entered 54321 so the output must be "allen".
how? :( Please help me.
Thank You

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Is it only the `account number` you want to do the lookup with?

Comment: I already get/retrieve the accname but only in the first line. But my problem now is what if i want to retrieve the accname in the second line?

Comment: show us your code. It would be easy for us to point out the problem rather than writing the whole thing.

Comment: Sir , I already solved the problem I am facing with... BY the way SIR, THANKS A LOT. BECAUSE YOU REPLIED TO MY QUESTIONS. I just keep on working on it then I accidentally found the problem :) THANKS FOR YOUR REPLY AND CONCERN SIR.

Comment: But sir, I need you later on this coding. Sorry for bad english I'm from Philippines.

Comment: You can answer your own question here and accept it as an answer.

Comment: @KeanAllen: also, writing in ALL CAPS is the equivalent of shouting. Don't do that.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry for that sir. I was just really happy :) Hope you guys understand :)